# Google Scripts error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (line 119, file "Code")

Tags: string, google-apps-script, syntax-error, html-templates

I get the following ERROR

Google Scripts error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (line 119, file "Code")

Doesn't look to me like there are any extra chevrons.

http://prntscr.com/rvzsqd

```
   "{ ?> <?!= <p><span style='color:green'>Authorized Successfully</span></p> } else {?> <?!= <p><span style='color:red'>Not Authorized</span></p> }").evaluate()
```

Comment: post code text and not image. See [ask]

Comment: It would be nicer if you could provide your code as an editable document so that the community could test your code without having to retype it, but the first thing visible at the first glance is that the content of line 119 begins with a double quote but ends with a single quote.

Comment: I've added the problem line

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following for the string template. I think the problem is how you use the `<?!` syntax.

```
var template = "<b><a href='<?= getService().getAuthorizationUrl() ?>' target='_blank'>Click to Authorize</a></b><br/><? if (getService().hasAccess()) { ?> <p><span style='color:green'>Authorized Successfully</span></p> <? } else { ?> <p><span style='color:red'>Not Authorized</span></p> <? } ?>";
```

It's also a bit cleaner if you keep a separate HTML template file (I much prefer that, even for simple pages).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>
      <a href='<?= getService().getAuthorizationUrl() ?>' target='_blank'>Click to Authorize</a>
    </b>
    <br/>
    <? if (getService().hasAccess()) { ?> 
      <p>
        <span style='color:green'>Authorized Successfully</span>
      </p>
    <? } else { ?> 
      <p>
        <span style='color:red'>Not Authorized</span>
      </p> 
    <? } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```