# Google-apps-script SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, syntax-error

I have a problem with the doGet () function.If it always runs error *SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' (line 12, file "Code")*

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var range = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A3").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValue(); 
  
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page');
  
  tmp.list = range;//.map(function(r){return r[0];} );
  
   return tmp.evaluate();
  
}
```

[image]
Where could be the problem?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: For a more detailed answer please add a [mcve] (at this time the question doesn't include the code of `page.html`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer..After your answer, I looked at the HTML code and found an error. thanks again for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that the problem is in the file `page.html`.

Related

- [Google Webapp: How to dynamically pass array values to jquery script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58811225/1595451)
- [Google Scripts error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (line 119, file "Code")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61118144/1595451)